# How can you get an entry type's name from its handle in a template?

Tags: entry-type, sections

Each of my entry types have their own template.

The url is something like:

```
/foo/{entryTypeHandle}
```

And the route is:

```
'foo/(?P<routesEntryTypeHandle>[-\w]+)' => 'bar.html'
```

In the template I can get the section the entry type is in:

```
{% set section = craft.sections.getSectionById(5) %}
```

And I can get ALL the entry types:

```
{% set entryTypes = section.getEntryTypes() %}
```

And I can get all the entries of that entry type:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(section).type(routesEntryTypeHandle) %}
```

But I can't seem to get the entry type's name.

In the Sections Service there's a method called `getEntryTypesByHandle` but that's not available in the model.

I could get the entry type name from the `entries`, but that relies on there actually being results, which isn't assured.

```
{{ entries.first.type.name }}
```

I must be missing an easier way. Anyone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Classic find the answer straight after posting.

The getEntryTypes method of the sections model allows you to choose how the array is indexed. This means you can do this:

```
{% set entryTypes = section.getEntryTypes('handle') %}
```

Which means our entry type model can be accessed using:

```
{% set entryType = entryTypes[routesEntryTypeHandle] %}
```

And the name:

```
{{ entryType.name }}
```

Answer (score 16):

A simpler way to do this might be:

```
{{ entry.type.name }}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer.

Comment: There is also `entry.type.handle` which is a bit better for "code" checks.